How to create a trigger to update columnA using columnB value after insert in postgresDB?
I am loading data to postgresDB from a csv file using psql in shell and want to create trigger which updates columnA using columnB value.
Postgres DB -
TableA - (columnA, columnB, stripped_columnA, stripped_columnB)
I am loading data to TableA using psql in Shell.
Loading only columnA and columnB.
And trying to use a trigger which updates stripped_columnA using columnA value like below
create or replace function strip_vol()
returns tigger as $$
begin
  new.stripped_columnA := lower(REGEX_REPLACE(new.columnA, '[-| |.|\\/]', '', 'g'));  
--tried new.stripped_columnA := new.columnA too.
  new.stripped_columnB := lower(REGEX_REPLACE(new.columnB, '[-| |.|\\/]', '', 'g'));
  return new;
end $$ language plpgsql;

create trigger abc_trigger
after insert on tableA
for each row/statement --tried both row and statement
execute procedure strip_vol();

But its not working.

An after trigger cannot change the row's data. You need before insert on tableA for each row.

Do you intend that columnA and stripped_columnA always maintain their relationship as defined by the regular expression or do you plan on subsequently updating these values independently? If the relationship is maintained then you may be better off with a generated column or even with a view.
